# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30

Tags: android-studio

I am creating my first android application which has a navigation bar that takes the user to 5 fragments. I have been encountering this error for 2 days and I am frustrated by it. I am handling fragments incorrectly or what is going on. I dont even know how to read the error. I am pretty sure that all the names and references match all over my code because I have checked it several times alread.

Full Error statement:

<sup>FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.navogation_with_pages, PID: 3022
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.navogation_with_pages/com.example.navogation_with_pages.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30 in com.example.navogation_with_pages:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #30 in com.example.navogation_with_pages:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30 in com.example.navogation_with_pages:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #30 in com.example.navogation_with_pages:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30 in com.example.navogation_with_pages:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:536)
at android.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:53)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3553)
at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:105)
at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:7370)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:229)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1073)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
at com.example.navogation_with_pages.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:49)
at com.example.navogation_with_pages.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:43)
at com.example.navogation_with_pages.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8305)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8284)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
2023-05-07 15:02:01.254  3022-3022  AndroidRuntime          com.example.navogation_with_pages    E      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)</sup>